# Diccionario de diccionarios

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Muestro a continuación, un script que importa cotizaciones históricas de diferentes valores de las bolsas, desde Yahoo, utilizando **'pandas_datareader'**.

```
# 1 - Define `tickers` & `company names` for every instrument
stocks      = {'AAPL':'Apple', 'MSFT':'Microsoft', 'AMZN' : 'Amazon',  'GOOG': 'Google', 'FB':'Facebook','NFLX':'Netflix' ,  'NVDA' : 'NVIDIA'}
bonds       = {'HCA' : 'HCA', 'VRTX' :  'VRTX'}
commodities = {'BTC-USD' : 'Bitcoin', 'PA=F' : 'Palladium'}
instruments = {**stocks, **bonds, **commodities}
tickers     = list(instruments.keys())
instruments_data = {}
N = len(tickers)


# 2 - We will look at stock prices over the past years, starting at January 1, 2015
#                               01-01-2015 - 16-04-2020
start = datetime.datetime(2015,1,1)
end   = datetime.datetime(2020,4,16)

# 3 - Let's get instruments data based on the tickers.
# First argument is the series we want, second is the source ("yahoo" for Yahoo! Finance), third is the start date, fourth is the end date
for ticker, instrument in instruments.items():
  print("Loading data series for instrument {} with ticker = {}".format(instruments[ticker], ticker))
  instruments_data[ticker] = web.DataReader(ticker, data_source = 'yahoo', start = start, end = end)
```

La sentencia `instruments = {**stocks, **bonds, **commodities}` , intuyo que crea un diccionario con tres diccionarios. No entiendo qué función tienen los dos '**'. Agradeceré me expliquéis esta sentencia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gracias a esto python trata lo que le das como key-value, con esto copia el diccionario con key-value dentro del nuevo diccionario.

Teniendo los siguientes diccionarios:

```py
stocks      = {'AAPL':'Apple', 'MSFT':'Microsoft', 'AMZN' : 'Amazon',  'GOOG': 'Google', 'FB':'Facebook','NFLX':'Netflix' ,  'NVDA' : 'NVIDIA'}
bonds       = {'HCA' : 'HCA', 'VRTX' :  'VRTX'}
commodities = {'BTC-USD' : 'Bitcoin', 'PA=F' : 'Palladium'}
```

**Ejemplo:**

La parte de tu codigo:

```py
instruments = {**stocks, **bonds, **commodities}
print(instruments)
```

Esto enseña el siguiente diccionario (Todos los diccionarios en uno solo):

```py
{'AAPL': 'Apple', 'MSFT': 'Microsoft', 'AMZN': 'Amazon', 'GOOG': 'Google', 'FB': 'Facebook', 'NFLX': 'Netflix', 'NVDA': 'NVIDIA', 'HCA': 'HCA', 'VRTX': 'VRTX', 'BTC-USD': 'Bitcoin', 'PA=F': 'Palladium'}
```

Sin embargo, si pones solo un asterisco (*) copia solo el key.

**Ejemplos (Utulizando los diccionarios de antes):**

```py
instruments = {*stocks, *bonds, *commodities}
print(instruments)
```

Muestra el siguiente set (Los keys de todos los diccionarios en un set):

```py
{'PA=F', 'NVDA', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'BTC-USD', 'VRTX', 'AAPL', 'FB', 'HCA', 'NFLX'}
```

Y este otro ejemplo:

```py
instruments = (*stocks, *bonds, *commodities)
print(instruments)
```

Muestra la siguiente tupla (Los keys de todos los diccionarios en una tupla):

```py
('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'FB', 'NFLX', 'NVDA', 'HCA', 'VRTX', 'BTC-USD', 'PA=F')
```

Y por ultimo:

```py
instruments = [*stocks, *bonds, *commodities]
print(instruments)
```

Muestra la siguiente lista (Los keys de todos los diccionarios en una lista):

```py
['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'FB', 'NFLX', 'NVDA', 'HCA', 'VRTX', 'BTC-USD', 'PA=F']
```

Answer (score 1):

Quisiera agregar que los dos asteriscos ** significan un número arbitrario de argumentos.

Son útiles cuando una función puede admitir un número arbitrario/desconocido de argumentos. Convierte esas variables en un diccionario, efectivamente, y la función puede verificar que cierta variable fue introducida al revisar las llaves.

```
def miFunc(**miDict):
    print(miDict)
    if 'pago' in miDict.keys():
        print("Pago procesado.")
    else:
        print("Transacción cancelada: Fondos insuficientes.")
    
miFunc(naranjas=3,manzanas=10)
# Resultado:
# {'naranjas': 3, 'manzanas': 10}
# Transacción cancelada: Fondos insuficientes.

miFunc(naranjas=3,manzanas=10,pago=3.5)
# Resultado:
# {'naranjas': 3, 'manzanas': 10, 'pago': 3.5}
# Pago procesado.
```

Funciones que admiten un número arbitrario de argumentos son útiles cuando estás procesando textos de tamaño/largo arbitrario. Cada palabra viene siendo etiquetada con información semántica o gramatical, por ejemplo, para procesar el sentimiento de un comentario.

Vale la pena apuntar que ya en python3.9 esta sentencia

```
instruments = {**stocks, **bonds, **commodities}
```

se puede reformular:

```
instruments = stocks | bonds | commodities
```

Yo lo veo como más legible, lo que debe ser la programación.

Comment: Se me olvido comentar lo de python3.9, gracias por esto. Por otro lado... la pregunta habla por la copia de diccionarios y al no haber funciones como tal decidi no hacer mencion a esto, de todas formas, gracias por añadirlo tambien.